# Баг с отменой голосования за быстро измененный ответ

Tags: дефект

Проголосовал за ответ. Ответ был изменен, но быстро, поэтому не отмечен, как измененный. Хочу отменить свой голос, но не могу, потому что

> Сейчас ваш голос блокирован до тех пор, пока ответ не будет отредактирован.

Comment: Если это багрепорт, то тут его никто из разработчиков SE не прочитает. Если проблема, то решение вы неверное и так знаете - сделать любую правку, тут же откатить ей, снять голос.

Comment: [by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62219/339911), но вопрос достаточно старый, поэтому можно попробовать перерассмотрение.

Comment: @Kromster это не решение, а уродливый костыль, к тому же доступный не для всех.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я и рассчитывал, что не первый, кто это заметил :) Но коли 15 лет уже так, то вряд ли вообще когда-то изменится.